# How do I compare two Strings being used for URLs

Tags: java, android, url, equals

I am writing an application which looks at a file hosted on a server and if it changes it loads reloads a webview. This is used to replicate a number of webpages across devices.

I set an initial url using:

```
private String originalURL;
private String newURL;
```

Then define the one to use on onCreate

```
originalURL = "https://www.buzzfeed.com/sallytamarkin/total-body-workouts#.moYPngWVWy";
```

I then run an async task on a timer:

```
private static String getUrlContents(String theUrl)
{
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    // many of these calls can throw exceptions, so i've just
    // wrapped them all in one try/catch statement.
    try
    {
        // create a url object
        URL url = new URL(theUrl);

        // create a urlconnection object
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

        // wrap the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

        String line;

        // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            content.append(line + "\n");
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content.toString();
}

private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // perform your network logic here
        String output  = getUrlContents("http://52.30.226.234/url.txt");
        System.out.println("output is " + output);
        newURL = output;
        return "YourResult";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Update your screen with the results.
    }
}
```

When I try to compare the two strings however they always evaluate as different. I have tried match(), equals() and equalsIgnoreCase(). This is the code I am using

```
if ((originalURL.equals(newURL))==true) {
                System.out.println("SAME");
            } else {
                System.out.println("NOT SAME");
            }
        }
```

I have also tested this with two strings defined earlier and it works fine.

I can only think this is because of special characters but have tried several fixes to remove special characters and this has not worked either.

Please help!

Comment: What is the content of the URL you download? If it isn't a URL itself, then your variable name should be more descriptive

Comment: Have you tried `originalURL.trim().equals(newURL.trim())`?

Comment: I believe Your originalUrl does not have `\n` (new line) at the end. So Why are you putting it in newUrl: `content.append(line + "\n");`

Comment: It was the adding of the new line character which I was missing. Thanks so mucg Bogdan

Answer (score 1):

Don't write "true" in your `if-clause` ;

Do this if you want `Case-Sensitive`:

```
if(string1.equals(string2)){
    System.out.println("SAME");
 } 
 else{
    System.out.println("NOT SAME");              
}
```

Do this if you want `Case-Insensitive`:

```
if(string1.equalsIgnoreCase(string2)){
    System.out.println("SAME");
 } 
 else{
    System.out.println("NOT SAME");              
}
```

If it doesn't fit what you want, or you wanna make a more rigorous comparison try using [Collator](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Collator.html)

Answer (score -1):

Probably due to the gibberish part of the url at the end. This part changes often. Print to see whether they are same.